# Why is the following CSS rule not working?

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

I have an image in my markup:

```
<img src="http://img-url/img.jpg" />
```

This is my CSS:

```
img {
  clip-path: polygon(70% 0%, 60% 40%, 90% 90%, 0% 50%) fill-box;
}
```

It works if I remove the `fill-box` part. So, am I using it the wrong way? The syntax from MDN seems to be:

```
<clip-source> | [ <basic-shape> || <geometry-box> ] | none
where 
<clip-source> = <url>
<basic-shape> = <inset()> | <circle()> | <ellipse()> | <polygon()>
<geometry-box> = <shape-box> | fill-box | stroke-box | view-box
```

Link to the property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Am I not using it correctly? What do I need to change?

Comment: I wonder if support for that (just the geometry box and not clip path on the whole) is available in any browser.

Comment: what browser are you using? http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the reason is that browsers don't support the functionality yet that you're trying to use.

The MDN docs you referenced are good, but don't really explain the browser support position, though the article does start with a warning that it is still 'experimental technology'.

WebPlatform is another good reference, and its [docs for clip-path](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/clip-path#Syntax) don't even mention fill-box.

You might also find that the supported syntax for clipping differs within SVGs compared with regular HTML elements, even within the same browser. In particular, fill and stroke are SVG properties, so using `fill-box` or `stroke-box` in an HTML context may or may not make sense.

The browser support for these edge-case syntaxes may improve over time, but for now the best option I can suggest is to pare down your usage to the syntax that works across current browsers.

Comment: The spec says `fill-box` or `stroke-box` kind of become `border-box` for CSS basic shapes.

Comment: Thanks Spudley, your explanation helped.

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax is

```
`img {
  clip-path: polygon(70% 0%, 60% 40%, 90% 90%, 0% 50%);
}`
```

or

```
`img {
  clip-path: fill-box;
}`
```

because fill-box is keyword value.
if you are using webkit based browsers try

```
`img {
  -webkit-clip-path: fill-box;
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

If you go to [the compatibility chart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path#Browser_compatibility), you'll see you might need vendor-prefixes.

If you're using Chrome or Firefox, you need to use `-web-kit-clip-path`.

Comment: If you see the MDN page (and the spec), it says the following - *<geometry-box> If specified **in combination with a <basic-shape>**, it provides the reference box for the basic shape.*

Comment: @Harry You're right. I was not familiar with the double-bar syntax.